# c# - is there a terser way to check if a variable is one of multiple things?

Tags: c#, if-statement, var

so currently I'm doing this:

```
if(variable == thing1 || variable == thing2 || variable == thing3)
```

But that's not super readable. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
if(variable == thing1 || thing2 || thing3)
```

Does such a syntax exist in c#?

Comment: Both syntaxes exist but do completely different things.

Comment: Don't sacrifice clarity for shortness.  Having said that, there are some good answers below already.  Just make sure that above all it is easier to read for the next guy/gal, not harder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If concise syntax is very important to you, you could define an extension method:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T item, params T[] elements)
    {
        return elements.Contains(item);
    }
}
```

You could then use this like so:

```
if (variable.In(thing1, thing2, thing3))
```

That said, if the list being checked against will not change, I would prefer to declare it as a static readonly field, and call `Contains` against that. The above extension method may result in a new array being allocated each time it is called, which can hurt performance in tight loops.

```
private static readonly Thing[] _things = new [] { thing1, thing2, thing3 };

public void ProcessThing(Thing variable)
{
    if (_things.Contains(variable))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Also, if the list being checked against contains more than a few items, use a `HashSet<T>` instead.

Comment: Oww... nice syntax... just as OP asked :-)

Comment: Is there a reason for this not to be allowed as the OP's pseudo-code?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: It's a matter of language design. There are considerations that would need to be made, such as type conversions, short-circuiting, operator associativity, and so on. If anything, I'd be more inclined to have SQL-like syntax with the `in` keyword, which gets very similar to the above extension method.

Comment: Worth to note: `params` will [always allocate array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38679180/1997232).

Answer (score 3):

Put the test strings in an list or array and call `Contains`.:

```
var testers = new [] { "foo1", "foo2" };

if (testers.Contains("subject"))
{
   // test succeeded
}
```

As an alternative:

```
if (new [] {"foo1", "foo2"}.Contains("subject"))
{
   // test succeeded
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some people prefer an extension method:

```
public static bool IsOneOf<T>(this T self, params T[] values) => values.Contains(self);
```

or similar.

Then you can say:

```
if (variable.IsOneOf(thing1, thing2, thing3))
```

Oops, I see Douglas was first with this approach.

It uses the default equality comparer of `T` implicitly.

The disadvantage is that you create an extension method to all types. If you only need it for e.g. `string`, you may of course create a less general extension method.

Answer (score 1):

You cound do:

```
int[] aux=new int[]{1,2,3}; 
if(Array.contains(aux, value))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put all your things into a collection of some sort then yes, you can use LINQ and `Any`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If Linq, why not `Contains`?

Comment: Why not any of the 1,000,000 ways, including the code submitted for replacement?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

1. Use `switch` (if `thing1`-`thing3` are constant expressions)

   ```
   switch variable
       case thing1:
       case thing2:
       case thing3:
           DoSomething();
           break;
   ```
2. Use a RegEx (only works for strings)

   ```
   if (RegEx.Match(variable, "^(thing1|thing2|thing3)"))
   {
       DoSomething();
   }
   ```
3. Use an array

   ```
   string[] searchFor = new string[] {thing1, thing2, thing3};
   if (searchFor.Contains(variable))
   {
       DoSomething();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This looks nice to me.  If variable = 479 or 482 or 1482 or etc.

```
if (new int[] { 479, 482, 1482, 2760 }.Contains(variable))
{
    DoSomething();
}
```